# Releasing compressed air with the loudest pop

Tags: aerodynamics, valves, compressed-air, noise

Due to the dry summer I've been thinking about theory of making cracker/banger without fire. Would connecting a nozzle (de Laval?) to quick release valve from small cylinder with the pressurised air to let's say 1MPa create a noticeable bang when exhausted?

Comment: paintball markers can be quite loud

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, I purchased a "rocket" toy which used thin plastic disks to create a pressure chamber near the exhaust end of the rocket. Air pressure was applied to the chamber until a level was reached sufficient to burst the disk. The result was flight to altitude but also a pretty substantial bang.

As you do not need to have flight, you should be able to create a chamber with the means to secure a thin disk for the noise/bang purpose alone.

The dimension of the rocket was about 25 mm in diameter. I suspect that if one creates a larger diameter chamber and larger diameter disk, the noise will also be enlarged.

Your material choices could be as simple as a disk cut from ordinary paper for a not-so-loud bang, to thin plastic such as that found in, for example, vegetable or fruit packages. Moving up to louder bangs may require materials such as those from detergent bottles or similar.

I envision a pipe with threaded ends, aka a pipe nipple, of suitable diameter for your budget. Pipe caps for both ends with one end threaded for an air valve or fitting while the other end is drilled out for the exhaust port. One would want to ensure a good seal, perhaps by filing smooth the threaded end of the pipe and making a matching gasket pair for each side of the bang disk.

I'm not sure about a quick release creating a particularly loud bang, but one could create what is known as a quick-dump mechanism often used in sprinkler systems. Rainbird™ has created a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rokXHhxRSw) explaining the mechanism. These have been used to trigger compressed air potato cannons for which the source of air is a reservoir tank of high pressure air. Simply turning a valve would result in much less mass applied to the potato, while the quick-dump provides the necessary force to launch the potato with great velocity.

Answer (score 0):

A neat idea.  Firecrackers make noise because the gunpowder burns, generating gas until the paper wrapper bursts, making the pop.  The sudden release of the compressed gas makes the noise. Sudden release is the key.

> (Slight digression) Years ago, I was working in the Admin building at a power plant and
> "BANG," the building shook.  A moment later, "BANG" and the
> building shook.  I was in the middle of the building in the basement
> and it was LOUD.  I had to find out what was going on so I went
> outside and they were venting 1400 PSI steam (about 10MPa).  I was
> almost a half a mile away, I'd see the puff of steam and a moment
> later get hit with the sound.  My (limited) understanding is there was
> an overpressure and the values opened (quickly) just long enough to
> bring the pressure down, they closed and the pressure built up again.

If you pressurize a Coke bottle sized vessel until a cork pops out of the top, that will make a noise.  It should be possible to extend that with bigger corks or bigger vessels and get bigger pops.  A little searching on the web shows that two liter Coke bottles start to rupture at a bit below 1MPa.  Keep in mind that air at those pressures can propel a 1.2 g cork (or pieces of a Coke bottle) fast enough to go through you.

Another idea that kind of single use and more dangerous is to make a pipe bomb that will blow up because you are applying air pressure.  In the US, there is a home center in every town that sells PVC tubing.  They sell schedule 40, somewhat thick wall that can handle probably 5MPa but you don't want that. They also sell thin wall irrigation tubing that I would expect would blow up if 1MPa were applied.  If you were to buy the tubing for a closed end tube, say 25 mm diameter by 250mm with fittings to connect up your source of high pressure air, it would blow up.  Keep in mind that you will have PVC shrapnel and this will very probably be more dangerous than the gun powder equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Before cap guns, the common toy was a "pop gun", using pressurized air and a cork. You can still buy them online or at some toy stores. The noise made by a toy pop gun is intentionally more of a 'pop' than a 'bang', but it demonstrates what is possible even with very low pressure and fairly slow release.

Champagne corks pop slightly louder than toy pop guns, unless levered out gently, which demonstrates that it's the speed of release, not the relative pressure which is important (around 4 atmospheres or 60 pounds pressure)